# PayPal payment button using information from HTML input form?

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment

I am creating a website which lets the user pay using Paypal.

Is it possible to have a form beforehand which asks for the buyer's name and shipping address, and information is taken from this when the buyer click's the Paypal "Buy Now" button. This will mean they see the information they have entered in Paypal's "Shipping address" section.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the paypal menu and your information menu on the same page? If it is, then you could use Javascript by getting the value of the input:

```
$address = document.getElementById('id').value;
```

and past it in the paypal form:

`document.document.getElementById('paypal_address_id').value = $address`;

Or if they are on separate pages you could use a form for gathering the information from the user:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
    <input type='text' name="example"/>
    <input type='text' name="example"/>
    <input type='text' name="example"/>
    <button type='submit' name="example"></button>
</form>
```

Then save it to a session variable so it can be carried to the next page:

```
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['example'];
```

and echo the results to the paypal menu:

```
<input type="text" name="paypal_address" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['example']?>"/>
```